# Does the use of infinity imply or is shorthand for a limit to infinity

Tags: infinity

So, is $\frac{1}{\infty}$ shorthand for $\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{1}{x}$ like an improper integral implies a limit being infront of it?

Comment: What, if anything, $1/\infty$ means, depends on the context in which it is used. If you give a full example, we can probably tell you what it means in that example.

Comment: "$\frac{1}{\infty}=0$" is a thumb-rule meaning that a bounded numerator and a denominator tending to $\infty$ or $-\infty$ give a fraction tending to $0$.

Comment: Any thoughts, John?